# Advancing index keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array with numerical incrementing keys starting at `0`, like `0 1 2 3 4 5 ....etc`. I need to assign new keys to the array in the following manner

- The first three keys keep their index number
- Every 4th key gets incremented by `4`
- The two keys after the fourth gets incremented by `1`again

I know I need to use a `foreach` loop ( seems the simplest way anyway ) to build a new array with newly assigned keys. My problem is the calculation of the keys

### HERE IS WHAT I HAVE SEEN IN RELATION

Here is my current array keys

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

and this is what I need them to be

> 0 1 2 6 7 8 12 13 14 18 19 20 24 25 26 30

Lets break this down into 3 key groups with the old array key on the top and the new array key at the bottom

1st group

> 0 1 2
>
> 0 1 2

2nd group

> 3 4 5
>
> 6 7 8

3rd group

> 6    7    8
>
> 12 13 14

4th group

> 9  10  11
>
> 18 19 20

etc etc......

When you look at the relationship between the two array keys, you'll see the following:

- The old array keys `0`, `1` and `2` keep their key value
- The old array keys `3`, `6`, `9` etc, if multiplied by `2`, gives you the new array key value
- The old array keys `4`, `7`, `10` etc, if multiplied by `2` and you subtract `1` from that total, you get the new array key for that specific key
- The old array keys `5`, `8`, `11` etc, if multiplied by `2` and you subtract `2` from the total, you get the new array key for that specific key

Alternatively, if you subtract the old key from the new key, you get the following answer

- `0` for the 1st group
- `3` for the 2nd group
- `6` for the 3rd group
- `9` for the 4th group
- etc etc.....

### POSSIBLE SOLUTION

The only solution I can think of is to use the modulus operator (*inside my `foreach` loop*), check the current key against the modulus result and then calculate my new key

Example:

```
if ( $key%3 == 0 && $key != 0 ) {
    $new_key = $key * 2;
} elseif ( ( $key - 1 ) %3 == 0 && $key != 1 ) {
    $new_key = ( $key * 2 ) - 1;
} elseif ( ( $key - 2 ) %3 == 0 && $key != 2 ) {
    $new_key = ( $key * 2 ) - 2;
} else {
    $new_key = $key;
}

$new_array[$new_key] = $value;
```

### MY QUESTION

Isn't there a smarter more mathematical way of doing this?

Comment: The person who voted to close this as unclear, what the hell don't you understand about this question?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this behaviour?

Comment: This is more wordpress related actually, I need to run a loop, and break each post into two sections, the first section will hold the post info from the first 3 posts, after which the next section will hold the second section of these three posts, after which the next three posts will show as laid out previously. I hope this makes sense :-) @GordonM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$new_key = floor($old_key / 3) * 3 + $old_key
```

Comment: Aggghhhh crap, had this in mind, totally forgot about `floor` to give me the lowest full integer from my calculation. Thanks for your answe

Answer (score 1):

If you use modulous you can generate a sequence with items missing.  The below code demonstrates how to do that.

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 40; $x++) 
{
    echo ("$x, " . ($x % 6) . ", " . ($x % 6 < 3? "true": "false") . "\n");
}
```

The output is:

```
0, 0, true
1, 1, true
2, 2, true
3, 3, false
4, 4, false
5, 5, false
6, 0, true
7, 1, true
8, 2, true
9, 3, false
10, 4, false
11, 5, false
12, 0, true
13, 1, true
14, 2, true
15, 3, false
16, 4, false
17, 5, false
18, 0, true
19, 1, true
20, 2, true
21, 3, false
22, 4, false
23, 5, false
24, 0, true
25, 1, true
26, 2, true
27, 3, false
28, 4, false
29, 5, false
30, 0, true
31, 1, true
32, 2, true
33, 3, false
34, 4, false
35, 5, false
36, 0, true
37, 1, true
38, 2, true
39, 3, false
```

If you use `$x` as a key only when `$x % 6 < 3` you can get the sequence you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = range(1,15);

For ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) echo $keys[] = $i + floor($i/3)*3;
$new_array = array_combine($keys, $array);
var_dump($new_array);
```